# Please help! We have an air conditioning and breaker issue

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, circuit-breaker

What is going on if we experience no cool air from our air conditioner?

Our inside temperature got up to 85° til we went outside to check out the AC unit and we saw and heard nothing but the refrigerant blowing out of the line. We then heard the AC breaker jump. It kept jumping turning the AC on.

Please help with any advice.

Comment: What make and model is this equipment?

Comment: Im not too sure what the make and model is?am srry its a house a.c. unit system

Comment: This should be edited to say AC instead of a.c. so people don't think you are talking about alternating current.

Comment: I would call a service company and ask for an estimate of the needed repairs

Comment: Could you rewrite your concerns and give a brief description of your past problems and concerns. What issues did you previously have and what is happening now. There are many experienced guys watching this site but they need a good explanation of the problems, type of equipment, and if you can pictures of the equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Your air conditioner is broke. Call a reputable cooling service contractor.

This is not a DIY type propblem.